# Best way to categorize sql columns

Tags: php, sql

Just wandering what would be the best way to group together different sql columns.

I have about 30 columns which need to split into Male and Female. It's not really visually appealing to have M/fieldname plus other categories are a lot more complex and I need to be able to foreach field find the column category.

Should I have a column category table or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: More information on what you're trying to achieve would help as there might be an alternative solution to 30 columns

Comment: 30 columns? You are doing something wrong. Please, give us your table's structure.

Comment: It's a table with about 50,000 rows.  My columns might be.... 0-4,4-9,10-14.... ect. The problem is some of these are male and some are female and I would like to categorize them.  The data references amount of people in a certain region on the map

Comment: try normalisation....

Comment: You should edit your post and show your table structure. Otherwise advice will be very limited to what the best approach would be, and may not be perfect advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are splitting data by gender and age.  The better data structure is to essentially have each value as a separate row in a table.  Something like:

- id
- gender
- age
- cnt

You can then bring the data into a more denormalized structure when you query it.